# Is there a way to turn off modules for MVC when running side-by-side with WebForms?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

We're currently running WebForms and MVC apps side-by-side (in the same project) and are having some issues. WebForms app uses RadCompression module from Telerik, which is now giving us issues with MVC (namely, modifying a status code of the response ends up with "Content-encoding: gzip,gzip", but that's a different problem I'll have to write about).

My question is, is it possible to turn off RadCompression module for requests that are handled by the MVC app and only keep them for WebForms?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, [RadCompression is not supported for use with ASP.NET MVC](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/compression/radcompression-issues-when-an-mvc-action-attribute-returns-statuscode-500.aspx#2506341).

That being said, you can always subclass the `RadCompression` module and update your web.config entries to use the extended module. Then you can add any logic to turn enable/disable compression from within the module itself.

Alternatively, there are a couple of ways [described in the docs](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/compression.html) for turning off compression. You can try the `excludeHandlers` configuration section or extend the default MVC HttpHandler `MvcHandler` and decorate it with the `RadCompressionSettings` attribute (although I haven't tried either of these methods).

```
[Telerik.Web.UI.RadCompressionSettings(HttpCompression = Telerik.Web.UI.CompressionType.None)]  
public class MyMvcHandler : System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler
{
    ...
}
```